# Как добавлять задачи в OTL, чтобы они обрабатывались LIFO, а не FIFO?

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, omnithreadlibrary

Это перевод вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293575

---

Пишу приложение, которое сканирует папки с картинками и показывает их миниатюры в гриде. В гриде у меня стоит обработчик `OnDrawCell`, который добавляет задачу в OTL на чтение картинки и генерацию миниатюры (в фоне) и отрисовку ее на грид (в основном потоке). Всё работает отлично, кроме случаев, когда пользователь быстро проматывает грид - в очередь OTL добавляется сотня задач. А очередь работает по принципу FIFO (первый пришел - первый ушел), так что пользователю приходится ждать, пока не прогрузятся все предыдущие картинки, перед тем как он увидит те, на которые промотал.

Текущий код:

```
CreateTask(
  procedure(const task: IOmniTask)
    ....
  end)
.OnTerminated(
  procedure(const task: IOmniTaskControl)
  begin
  ....
  end)
.Unobserved
.SetPriority(tpIdle)
.Schedule;
```

Как мне добавлять задачи в OTL, чтобы они выполнялись по принципу LIFO (последний вошел - первый вышел)?

*Разумеется задачи которые уже выполняются не должны отменяться. Мне нужно, чтобы задачи из очереди добавленные в нее последними, первыми брались в обработку.*

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293575/how-to-add-tasks-to-otl-to-be-processed-lifo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением стэка** на стороне приложения.

Все запросы на получение миниатюр добавляются в стэк (получаем LIFO). На каждую новую задачу и завершение задачи вызывается функция добавления задач в очередь OTL до тех пор пока `GlobalOmniThreadPool.CountQueued >= 1`. Таким образом очередь OTL всегда заполнена задачами из верха стэка (самыми новыми).

В дополнении, если какая-либо миниатюра запрашивается несколько раз (например при скроле грида вверх-вниз), можно найти ее заявку в стэке и перенести наверх стэка, чтобы она была обработана как можно скорее.

** не просто стэк, а с методами поиска и перемещения по нему.